# Execute code from non .py file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to make python execute a random line of code from a given file. Let's say I have a file called "code_lines". This file contains random pieces of python code, ex.

```
print("This is a random message")
print("This is another message")
print("This is getting boring")
```

Is it possible for python to select a random line from that file and run it as code?

Comment: You can run `python your_file.whatever`, and it'll try to execute the file as Python code, but it won't be able to execute 'random lines'. It would try to treat the data in this file as ordinary Python code, though.

Comment: This question has already been asked. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704916/python-how-to-execute-code-from-a-txt-file

Comment: You can use `exec`. Unfortunately I can no longer place an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making use of `exec` statement. Of course, this can cause several problems in a real case scenario, since you are trying to execute random lines off a file, but it works for simple lines of code (like the ones you supplied in your example `code_lines.py`).

```
from random import randint

with open('code_lines.py') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    count = 0
    code =[]
    while line:
        code += [line]
        line = file.readline()
        count += 1
    exec(code[randint(0,count-1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `random` module to choose randomly, and `exec` to execute arbitrary Python code.

```
import random

with open('code_lines') as f:
    exec(random.choice(f.readlines()))
```

Warnings: `exec` and `eval` are super dangerous.  If someone else could write code to `code_lines` they can do pretty much whatever they want to your computer.  Also, if the line of code you select is dependent on other lines, it could potentially fail.

Comment: You probably meant `exec` and not `eval`

Comment: @officialaimm I actually forgot `exec` existed. Unsurprisingly, I've never used either for actual code I've written.