# How to get function value from txt file with exec Python

Tags: python, function, file, exec, python-exec

I want to execute python code from txt file and store it.

In txt file I have this code:

```
def func(a):
    return a
```

In python:

````
def random_file_input(file_name):
    ran_number = random.randint(0, 100)
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
        data = f.read()
        f.write(f"\nfunc({ran_number})")
        a = exec(data)  #-----> i want to store like this  :( 

random_file_input('python_code.txt') ```
````

Comment: A similar question already exists: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704916/python-how-to-execute-code-from-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

.txt file example:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")
```

first you need to read needed part of python code from .txt file

```
>>> with open("better.txt", 'r+') as f:
...     data = f.read()
```

and then execute it as python code

```
>>> exec(data)
```

now if you know name of function you are able to call function from .txt file and store results in variable

```
>>> b = hello()
>>> print(b)
Hello
```

## exec()

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) says: This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. *object* must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs). If it is a code object, it is simply executed.

#### But as it's mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704916/python-how-to-execute-code-from-a-txt-file) answer it's not safe

Comment: I tried it in editor but it returned error.
```
def random_file_input(file_name):
    ran_number = random.randint(0, 100)
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
        data = f.read()
        f.write(f"\ntinki({ran_number})")
        exec(data)
        a = hello()

random_file_input('python_code.txt')
```
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined. Did you mean: 'help'?

Comment: Have you defined hello() function in your .txt file?

Comment: yeah but editor doesn't like it.
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined.

Comment: Error only in editor, not while execution ? Because if so editor doesn't have any information about hello() function declaration, so it will mark it as NameError but will run well.

Comment: No while execution it returned error. Let me explain what I am trying to do.  The task is to create a function which will read another function from the txt file. The first function should pass the parameter to the second  and check if the result is more then 50.

Comment: LOL I changed .txt files on .py and its very easy why I choose txt really don't know :(

Comment: Definitely the best solution) Anyway why have you chosen such complex way to import functions? And it's really weird that you get error, can you pleas paste somewhere your code and share the link?